# Laravel 5.1 php artisan migrate with error message PDOException could not find driver

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5, artisan-migrate

I'm trying to connect to the PostgreSQL database through laravel in order to make a php artisan migrate , but I get the error

> [PDOException] could not find driver

looking at similar questions found there to enable extensions in `php.ini` but did not solve my problem, still gives me the same error.

In other parts of my code I use the database and I can add records so I think my settings database right. I do not understand the error.

***Database.php file:***

```
<?php return [ 
      'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 
      'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'), 
      'connections' => [ 
             'pgsql' => [ 
                  'driver' => 'pgsql', 
                  'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'), 
                  'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'), 
                  'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'), 
                  'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''), 
                  'charset' => 'utf8', 'prefix' => '', 
                  'schema' => 'public', 
              ], 
        ], 
        'migrations' => 'migrations', 
  ]; ?>
```

Comment: can you please post your `database.php` file ??

Comment: <?php

return [

   'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'),

    'connections' => [
        'pgsql' => [
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public',
        ],
    ],
    'migrations' => 'migrations',
];

Comment: My usual checks when deploying: make sure storage folder is writable by the user. Env file has correct details. Run command composer dump-autoload

Comment: Sometimes the env in server goes one lined , so check and break the single line , it caused me issues most of the times

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have `pdo_pgsql` extention.

You can

```
php -i | grep pgsql
```

to see it.